# Django Image watermarking procedure

Tags: python, django, image, watermark

I am using django in one of my web applications for an image oriented website.  I don't want to make these images available to unauthorized users so I decided to watermark the images with a transparent logo I have already made.  I found a module called `django-watermark` but I don't want to use it because its creator no longer maintains it.

How can I watermark the images without using that module?

Answer (score 4):

You should look into using [`django-imagekit`](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). 
I've started using it recently, and have found it to be pleasingly simple and powerful.

In [this report of watermarking images](http://miguelventura.pt/django-imagekit-watermarks.html), the author forks `django-imagekit`, but you should be able to copy/re-implement his processors. (See [`watermark.py` in his fork](https://github.com/mmv/django-imagekit/blob/develop/imagekit/processors/watermark.py)).

Comment: I now realise that the link report was not indeed a tutorial, but it did link to code that will solve the issue. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The link for the tutorial: http://miguelventura.pt/django-imagekit-watermarks.html